# How Install lego NXT stack on ROS fuerte?

Tags: nxt, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there any way to install the NXT ros stack in ROS fuerte?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33889/how-install-lego-nxt-stack-on-ros-fuerte?/) by [vicsaez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2374/vicsaez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The NXT package is still not supported in ROS Fuerte.

You can follow the official tutorial in the ROS Wiki, which is written for ROS Electric users.

---

Originally posted by [Flavio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3202/flavio/) with karma: 16 on 2012-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0